# How to get a field and update a textview from firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a value from Firestore but I am getting null every time. Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing? This is my Firestore collections and documents.

[image: FirestoreCollections]

```
DocumentReference docRef =  dbase.collection("newsImage").document("cqmpNF45IZsHDSx9hSuq");
colref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                str = document.getString("imgNews");
                tv.setText(str);
            } else {
                Log.d("docv", "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("docv", "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem comes from the following lines of code:

```
String newsText= ipustr;
tv.setText(sectorText);
```

Where you try to assign a value that doesn't come from the database. So most probably you should do something like this:

```
str = document.getString("imgNews");
tv.setText(str);
```

Or even simples:

```
tv.setText(document.getString("imgNews"));
```

**Edit:**

The name of the filed is incorrect, so please use:

```
tv.setText(document.getString("imgnews"));
```

Comment: Hey alex thanks for answering..but it was just typing mistake at the time of posting the question. i updated the code,,yet i am getting null

Comment: yes it working thanks